# Trying to install Fedora everything live media reboots the PC over and over

Tags: fedora, usb, live-usb, installer-anaconda

I'm looking towards moving to Fedora 35 from Ubuntu, but I'm trying to follow [This guide](https://github.com/Zer0CoolX/Fedora-KDE-Minimal-Install-Guide) to make a minimal KDE install via Fedora Everything. I've successfully flashed it with both Fedora Media Writer and Etcher on 3 different usb flash drives, but everytime I click "test this media and install Fedora" my PC reboots. [image: This is what it reboots to everytime]

I've tried 3 flash drives, 2 of them being new. I've also use Etcher and Fedora Media Writer. Does the Fedora everything iso have a different method of flashing to a USB? I can't even boot into the anaconda gui.

Comment: So I've figured out that I can boot into anaconda when I disable my SSD in BIOS... but I can't install Fedora onto it with it disabled. Even with the flash drive set to boot first this is occuring

Answer (score 0):

[This was the issue](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/no-local-disks-found-during-installation/12012/2)

"Check your disk mode in the bios : RAID, IDE or AHCI and switch from Raid to AHCI"

This fixed my problem.